# Building & Injecting Client

Tags: java, language-agnostic, inversion-of-control, guice

I have a 3rd party db client that I'd like to have Guice create and manage a singleton instance of and then inject were needed.

I understand that with Guice I can inject an "object", which in this case is a db client using an interface and implementation. But is it possible to have Guice directly create and make available a singleton db client, like spring allows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about the 'directly create' part, but there are at least two options to create a singleton:

**1. Annotate the implementation**

```
interface DbClient {
}

@Singleton
class DbClientImpl implements DbClient {
}

class DbClientModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(DbClient.class).to(DbClientImpl.class);
  }
}
```

**2. Bind as singleton**

```
interface DbClient {
}

class DbClientImpl implements DbClient {
}

class DbClientModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(DbClient.class).to(DbClientImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second option, as that allows the same class to be used as a singleton or not depending on context.

**Edit: object created by another library!**

No problem. here's how you'd handle that:

```
class DbClientModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    DbClient client = AnotherLibrary.createDbClient();
    bind(DbClient.class).toInstance(client);
  }
}
```

**Edit 2: what if the object I want to provide isn't available right away?**

No problem either. Here's what one could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DbClient client = SomeWeirdPlace.getDbClient();
  Injector injector = Guice.createInject(new MyModule(client));
  injector.getInstance(ServerInterface.class).start();
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  MyModule(DbClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(Client.class).toInstance(client);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a 3rd party db client that I'd like to create a singleton instance of and inject were needed via guice. Using either of the above methods, I'd be creating essentially a factory wrapper around the 3rd party client. Rather than doing that, is there a way for Guice to create a singleton instance and inject where annotated?

Comment: Your updated answer is almost exactly what I need. After a bit more research, I learned that using "@Provides" I can create a method that will produce the required object on demand. However, the ONLY remaining issue is that I need to pass the "@Provides" method an object that is created by the underlying framework when bootstrapped. Do you know how I can pass the object to the method in the AbstractModule implementation?

Comment: @iluxa, do not make any complex calls like `AnotherLibrary.createDbClient()` inside `configure()`! This will certainly lead to cryptic error messages and unexpected exceptions! `@Provides`-methods or `Provider`s should be used instead.

Comment: @Ari, if your database client has "an object thas is created by the underlying framework when bootstrapped` as a dependency, you can also manage this object by Guice (e.g. by defining another `@Provides`-method) and inject is as an argument to the `@Provides`-method which returns your DB client.

Comment: @Ari, BTW, you should also consider using scopes for your DB client. By default Guice always creates new instance of a dependency when it is needed (i.e. calls `@Provides`-method again and again), unless you define it as `@Singleton` - contrary to Spring, which creates singletones by default.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Can you provide an example of how the bootstrapped object can be injected as an argument to the `@Provides` method which retunrs the DB client? Also, is there a way to inject the bootstrapped object without having Guice manage it?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean - bootstrapped object? You have to create any object in some way, be it constructor call or factory method. So you almost always can create a `Provider` or `@Provides`-method to create all required objects and bring them under Guice control. If, for some reason, you cannot write a provider, you can pass an object to module constructor and create `toInstance()` binding.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev - "do not make any complex calls like AnotherLibrary.createDbClient() inside configure()" - well, that depends, right... When you're a server, it's often beneficial to spend a long time starting up but be certain that you're ready-to-go once you're there.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev By bootstrapped object, I mean an object the underlying framework instantiates at startup and makes available within its "main" method for further startup/config use.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question 100%, but see my latest edit

Comment: @Ari then you should do as iluxa wrote in his answer.